# Is Google Calendar API for .NET quick start discontinued?

Tags: c#, .net, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to integrate google calendars API into a winform based off this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNdpWph4Pi8&list=PLf2aHFQm4mSccCfY-B1YLkqXSAMbtltkT&index=14
the video is from 2019 and my guess is google discontinued .NET as there was a better option

https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/js
this link leads to the google calendar quick start page
i don't see .Net in the drop down

i found a link that appears to have the right information but i don't know if its the newest (or last) version

is there a more recent version? and was .net discontinued for google calendar api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, google has not discontiuned the .net calendar api.

Developer Guide: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started

Docs: https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3/latest/api/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.html

API-Reference: https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference?apix=true